# How can I find the proper focal length of the cameras in Five Nights at Freddy's using BLAM?

Tags: modeling, camera

It's been a long time since I last posted and I need your help. For a few months now,I've been trying to find the focal length of the security cameras in Five Nights at Freddy's. Every time I tried,it was always inconsistent. Then,I found BLAM (which I'm still unfamiliar with) and I tried using it to solve my dilemma,but it didn't work either. Could someone please help me?

P.S: I heard that BLAM has a new predecessor called ***fSpy***. Should I use it instead?

### Here's an example of some rooms from FNaF2 that I want to replicate in Blender:

***1. Main Hall***

[image]

***2. The Office***

[image]

[image]

***3. Parts & Services***

[image]

Comment: Download and watch this. Its Free. https://blenderartists.org/t/perfect-photo-and-camera-match-with-fspy-and-blender-2-79/1135878

Comment: Thank you. I'll watch it when I go back home.